# Unity facebook sdk 'Didn't find class "com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"' any more suggestions for this?

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine

How to replicate this error...

- Create a new Unity project.
- Import the facebook sdk unitypackage
- Set your App Id for facebook via Facebook\Edit Settings
- Using Assets\External dependency manager\Android, press 'Resolve dependencies', then press 'delete resolved libraries' (otherwise the build will fail at the gradle stage)
- Build and run.
- When the app tries to run I immediately get the error message on my phone 'app has stopped working'
  and see this error in the logs ...

  ```
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.SandwichGeneration.MakeASquare--nLEHpzOYlwW6XKmGzPfIw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.SandwichGeneration.MakeASquare--nLEHpzOYlwW6XKmGzPfIw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.SandwichGeneration.MakeASquare--nLEHpzOYlwW6XKmGzPfIw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
  ```

Suggested fixes I've tried [from here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-for-unity/issues/393)

1. I've tried different combinations of old or new facebook sdks and old or new versions of Unity.
2. I've tried building from a few different machines to different Android devices.
3. I've deleted the external dependency manager included with the facebook sdk and used [this one](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver) instead. In order to get this one to resolve I had to set a 'Custom Gradle Properties Template'in the player setting under publishing settings.
4. I've set a Custom Proguard file'in the player setting under publishing settings, and I added the following two lines to the file..

   ```
   -keep class com.facebook.internal.* {*;}
   -keep class com.facebook.* {*;}
   ```

So I've tried all the suggested fixes and various combinations thereof. I dont know what more I can do. Can anyone suggest anything else to try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok heres one specific method I followed where it worked.

- Unity version:   2019.3.15f1
- Facebook SDK version: 7.21.2
- Using the PlayServicesResolver, Resolve libraries
- **Do not** Delete Resolved Libraries
- Set a Custom Proguard file in the player setting under publishing settings, and add the following two lines to the file..

  ```
    -keep public class com.facebook.**{public *; } 
    -keep public class com.facebook.internal.**{ public *; }
  ```
- Comment out these lines from mainTemplate.gradle

  ```
       com.android.support:appcompat-v7
       com.android.support:support-v4
       com.android.support:customtabs
  ```

So your mainTemplate.gradle will look something like this...

```
    `// Android Resolver Repos End
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0' 
    // Android Resolver Dependencies Start
        //implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1' // Facebook.Unity.Editor.AndroidSupportLibraryResolver.addSupportLibraryDependency
        //implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1' // Facebook.Unity.Editor.AndroidSupportLibraryResolver.addSupportLibraryDependency
        //implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1' // Facebook.Unity.Editor.AndroidSupportLibraryResolver.addSupportLibraryDependency

        implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:6.0.0' // Assets/IronSource/Editor/ISFacebookAdapterDependencies.xml:8
        implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-applinks:[7.1.0, 8)' // Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Dependencies.xml:6
        implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:[7.1.0, 8)' // Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Dependencies.xml:8
        implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1' // Facebook.Unity.Editor.AndroidSupportLibraryResolver.addSupportLibraryDependency
        implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-gamingservices:[7.1.0, 8)' // Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Dependencies.xml:9
        implementation 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0' // Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Dependencies.xml:4
        implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-core:[7.1.0, 8)' // Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Dependencies.xml:5
        implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[7.1.0, 8)' // Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Dependencies.xml:7
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.4.0' // Assets/IronSource/Editor/ISAdMobAdapterDependencies.xml:8
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0' // Assets/IronSource/Editor/IronSourceSDKDependencies.xml:17
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.2.1' // Assets/IronSource/Editor/IronSourceSDKDependencies.xml:25
    // Android Resolver Dependencies End
    **DEPS**}`
```