# Why recipient launch a app by black screen?

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, invite

I use `FB.AppRequest` to invite friends on android and use Facebook Unity SDK. I want to achieve the following functions: if the friend has not installed the app, jump to the market to download the app, if the friend has installed the app, then invoke the app. Now the situation is that my friend received the invitation and clicked start in the Messenger. The application was launched, but the screen was black. How to solve this situation has troubled me for a few days.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Get your friend to uninstall and try installing from an apk, and see if it that works at all.

The facebook sdk for Unity can cause black screen on load on Android if it is having issues. Which it usually always does without some complicated workarounds.

My (different account) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64064133/unity-facebook-sdk-didnt-find-class-com-facebook-facebookcontentprovider-an/64066468#64066468) is how I got facebook sdk to work last time.

I found this workaround by chatting to people on the [facebook sdk git repo](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-for-unity/issues) who has posted simialar issues to mine. My fix was from almost a year ago, so u might want to ask around there as the fix has probably changed since then.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. After I rebuilt the app according to the method you provided, the same error still appeared, but I built a test app with android studio and found that everything was OK after testing. I still don’t know where it should appear. The error is in unity, do you have any new suggestions?